# Issue with svrepdesign object in tbl_svysummary

Tags: gtsummary

I have been having an issue with the tbl_svysummary function throwing an error when attempting to construct a table using a svrepdesign object (survey design object with replicate weights)  and the 'by' argument. This issue has been previously reported with relevant reprex on the gtsummary GitHub site (issues #1441, #1535), but happy to post another here if necessary. Just wondering if there is a timeline to fix this bug? Thanks!

Comment: I would consider this more if a feature request, rather than a bug. Unfortunately, there is no timeline at the moment. It's difficult to find dev time these days!

Comment: No problem, thank you for the quick reply and for all the fantastic work that you have done on the gtsummary package. It is a regular part of my analytic workflow and an essential package that I introduce my graduate students to. Much appreciated!